# Group Array of objects / adding object to an array correctly - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have found a few things on google about objects and grouping them, i want to group objects by the value key
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlRpu.png)

im not having any success and im not sure if its because im adding the objects to the array incorrectly in order to group them or i simply dont understand how to use the group function. here is how im adding my objects `PropData.push({value:Object.values(element1)[1],dbid: element })`

my desired output is to group the object by the value key so i would end up with three groups of dbids if you use the image above as an example output.

example of what i have tried -

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {       
            return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
                // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
                (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
                    currentValue
                );
                // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
                return result;
            }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
        };

        // Group by color as key to the person array
        const personGroupedByColor = groupBy(PropData, 'value');
```

as some people dont believe that i can use google here is another method i tried -

```
            var grouped = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(PropData, 'value'),
            clist => clist.map(elt => _.omit(elt, 'value')));

        console.log(grouped);
```

and here is the output in the console [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbIg1.png)

here is the cod i currently have -

declare array to store objects - `const PropData = [];`

loop through opbjects an if it complies with requirments add parts of the object to a new objects within and store in `propdata`

```
let Selected = "01.04 - Systems";
        // use Selected to group dbids 

    

        for (const element of NOP_VIEWER.getIsolatedNodes()) {
            NOP_VIEWER.getProperties(element, function (e) {

                //return the properties for each dbid
                for (const element1 of e.properties) {

                    if (Object.values(element1).indexOf(Selected) > -1) {

                        PropData.push({value:Object.values(element1)[1],dbid: element })

                        //var index = e.properties.findIndex(p => p.displayName == Selected);
                        //console.log('index of ',Selected, index, ' and dbid = ', element, 'properteis Value =', Object.values(element1)[1]);
                    }

                }

            }); 

        }
```

the output im currently getting is -

```
0: {value: 'HDG', dbid: 2607}
1: {value: 'HML', dbid: 2642}
2: {value: 'ELS', dbid: 249993}
3: {value: 'ELS', dbid: 250011}
4: {value: 'ELS', dbid: 250025}
5: {value: 'ELS', dbid: 250195}
6: {value: 'HGT', dbid: 266254}
```

My desired output is to group the by the value key, i guess it would look similar to this -

```
0: {value: 'HDG', [dbid: 2607]}
1: {value: 'HML', [dbid: 2642]}
2: {value: 'ELS', [dbid: 249993,dbid: 250011,dbid: 250025,dbid: 250195]}
6: {value: 'HGT', [dbid: 266254]}
```

the methods i have tried are further up in this post due to multiple edits.

Comment: What `group` function are you trying to use? It's unclear what specific issue you're having.

Comment: i have tried a few things and have now added one of the methods, all the ways i tried gave an output of a completely blank array. PropData is the array name and value the key i want to group by.

Comment: Note that `=` is an assignment; `==` is a comparison.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - thanks for this this is the method i tried, and saw that a lot of people had success with but this also just gave me a blank array. hence why i think im collecting the objects incorrectly in the first place

Comment: Instead of images add the code of your objects to the question and an example of the result you're after, it's then faster to understand an easier to help

Comment: @Corrl  - i hope the edits i have made helps explain the process.

Comment: What's your input? Isn't it an array with objects? But the output should be an object with numbers (the former indexes?) as keys? And the arrays in the objects have no keys...

Comment: I think I now get what the numbers at the beginning of the lines mean... this looks like a key in an object, but an array is logged like this in the conole with the indexnumbers. But this doesn't reflect the real structure and is rather confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve this?

```js
let objsArr = [
  { value: 'HDG', dbid: 2607},
  { value: 'HML', dbid: 2642},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 249993},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250011},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250025},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250195},
  { value: 'HGT', dbid: 266254}
]

function groupBy(arr, key) {

  return arr.reduce((result, current) => {

    let k = current[key]        
    let entry = result[k]
    
    if (entry) entry.push(current)
    else result[k] = [current]
    
    return result
  }, {})
}

console.log(groupBy(objsArr, 'value'))
```

Or is it this?

```js
let objsArr = [
  { value: 'HDG', dbid: 2607},
  { value: 'HML', dbid: 2642},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 249993},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250011},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250025},
  { value: 'ELS', dbid: 250195},
  { value: 'HGT', dbid: 266254}
]

function groupBy(arr, key) {

  return arr.reduce((result, current) => {

    let k = current[key]        
    let entry = result.find(elem => elem[key] === k)
            
    if (entry) {
      let index = result.indexOf(entry)
      result[index].dbid.push(current.dbid)
    }else {
      let obj = {}
      obj[key] = k
      obj.dbid = [current.dbid]
      result.push(obj)
    }    
    return result
  }, [])
}

console.log(groupBy(objsArr, 'value'))
```

Comment: Two issues in this part of the code `return grouped = objsArr.reduce`. What is `grouped` , where is it declared, and why do you use `objsArr` (the global variable) instead of the function argument?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for remarking! Both are errors due to rearranging the logic and of course don't make sense...

Comment: the output im after is the second one, but when i use the function im still getting a blank output array. the input you have looks the same as mine, i think i will need to do some further investigations to understand how my array is actually constructed. as im sure its a user error on my behalf